# Cast error from other name space

Tags: c#, list, model, casting

i am trying to use a list that is saved in another session.

but i get an error because the list model is made in another name space

Unable to cast object of type `'System.Collections.Generic.List1[OCC.CartItem]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[OCC.ShopCheckOut.CartItem]'`

```
List<CartItem> cart = new List<CartItem>();

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart" + HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID] != null)
            {
                cart = (List<CartItem>)HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart" + HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID];
        }
```

is ther a way to use the model from the othe name space??

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to convert between the two - e.g. using `List<T>.ConvertAll` or LINQ.

Basically the fact that the two classes have the same short name within the namespace is irrelevant - they're entirely different classes, really.

Of course if you're happy to just *use* the type that's actually in the session, that's fine - but if you really want a `List<OCC.ShopCheckOut.CartItem>` you'll need to perform a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If

> the list model is made in another name space

then just use the model from that namespace instead of declaring it anew:

```
List<ShopCheckOut.CartItem> cart = new List<ShopCheckOut.CartItem>();

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart" + HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID] != null)
        {
            cart = (List<ShopCheckOut.CartItem>)HttpContext.Current.Session["ShoppingCart" + HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID];
    }
```

or the other way around.

=> Declare your `CartItem` class at a reasonable location (maybe even within its own namespace) and use it from there in your other namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by reference the other namespace and use the cartItem from there